# How to determine that the file has finished downloaded

Tags: java, servlets, http-get

I am trying to calculate the bandwidth of the network by determining how much time does it take to download a fixed size file.

```
starttime=Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
HttpResponse response=cts.getContent();
if(response != null) 
   endtime=Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
```

Here is my `getContent()` method:

```
public HttpResponse getContent()
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet postRequest = new HttpGet("myserverurl");
        try {
             Log.i(tag,"before execute");
             HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
              Log.i(tag,"after execute");
            HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
              StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
              String line = null;
              while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                  sb.append(line + "\n");
              }
              is.close();
              Log.i(tag,sb.toString());
              response.toString();
              return response;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i(tag,"execption="+e);
            return null;
        }

    }
```

I calculate the end time when this method responds. My question is when is the right time to calculate the end time? If I take the endtime immediately after the line:

```
HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
```

The bandwidth I get is very high and when I do it after the while loop executes, the Bandwidth is completely different.

Which approach is the right one? When does the file gets downloaded completely?

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, it is synchronous, oppose to asynchronous, so right after the response is stored is where the download ends

Comment: So you mean I should discard the while loop? If I do that then the bandwidth I get is like 100Mbps which is a bit too high.

Comment: If you want to keep the loop, you could do something more efficient that using a string builder, eg, just count how many lines there are with a for loop if you know how many there are, so you are more precise by factoring out some bad time

Comment: I dont need the loop. I can remove it completely. I just need the time it took to download the file. My question is after which line is it correct to take the endtime? i.e does the file get downloaded after I do response.getEntity()?

Comment: If it's asynchronous, it's best to use a [semaphore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming))